# Hack 'n Slash: What debug buttons are enabled with the ENABLE_DEBUG_BUTTONS artefact?

Tags: hack-n-slash

What debug buttons are enabled with the ENABLE_DEBUG_BUTTONS artefact and what do they do?

Comment: I had my doubts, but [there really is a game called "Hack 'n' Slash"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hack_%27n%27_Slash).

Comment: @Nolonar yeah, it's a quirky one.  Your sword is a USB drive, and you edit the properties of objects you hit with it.  Not even kidding you.

Comment: @gatherer818 And that's not even getting into the later parts of the game, where things get even more crazy/meta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taken from http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=258974905&insideModal=1:

> Hold down the letter 't' and you can click with your mouse to teleport.
> The mouse cursor should appear and if you left click you will teleport there.
> This is very helpful if you get stuck in the scenery.
>
> The '[' and ']' buttons slow and speed time up, respectively.
>
> The ';' button will trigger an overlay of cool debug info.
>
> If you have a controller you can press  'L-Shoulder + R-Shoulder + Back + Start' to end the game.

Comment: Ah, that's very cool!

Comment: The teleport one is rather OP for the point you get it in the game, isn't it? I mean at that point you can already do just about anything, but the point of the game is figuring out how, and that artifact doesn't take much figuring out, more just trying different keys and seeing which ones work.